Moderator Agreement Archive
Since there is no archive of moderator agreements in Meta Stack Exchange, I have created this post. You can go through the previous versions of the Moderator Agreement in the answers.

It would be fun if you could post V1 as one answer, then for V2, post V1 as the answer again, then (5 mins later) update it to V2 so that the revision history shows the diff between the two, and for V3 post V1 as the answer, then edit to V2, then edit to V3 and so on

Though maybe posting, deleting immediately, then updating and undeleting could help shorten the grace period problem

Why not just go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement/versions/{version-number}? For example this is the first version

Would it be possible to add the effective date to the versions?

That there should be an archive here on Meta Stack Exchange, because the versions might disappear doesn't really hold water as an argument. If you feel there's a reason not to trust that Stack Exchange will keep versions of the Moderator Agreement available, then the archive shouldn't be kept on-site, as there's just as much reason to distrust any on-site "archive" as there is to distrust that the versioning won't be kept available. Thus, an archive that is off-site should be used, such as archive.org.

@testing-for-ya - v3 didn't disappear, it was never made publicly available (or even available to mods).

Version 1

In order to access the ♦ moderator functions, our community moderators must review and accept the following terms:
The agreement
I acknowledge and agree that as a moderator for Stack Exchange Inc.
i. I will abide by the then-current Terms of Service of Meta Stack Exchange, and other moderator policies made available to me,
ii. I acknowledge that I may have access to potentially personally-identifying information about Meta Stack Exchange users and that in connection with such access
a. I will use such information solely in accordance with the then-current Privacy Policy of Meta Stack Exchange,
b. I will not disclose this information to anyone,
c. I will not store or copy this information and
d. I will only use such information in connection with performance as a Meta Stack Exchange moderator for the benefit of Meta Stack Exchange.
I acknowledge and agree that I am an independent volunteer moderator to Meta Stack Exchange and I am not an employee, agent or representative of Stack Exchange Inc., and I have no authority to bind Stack Exchange Inc. in any manner. Stack Exchange Inc. reserves the right to terminate my privileges as a moderator at any time without warning.


Would it make sense to have the ToS and policy links point to archived versions, if available? Or did they perhaps change too much during the period the agreement was used?

If you have the archived links of the policies, feel free to edit the post.

Version 2

In order to access the ♦ moderator functions, our volunteer community
moderators must review and accept the moderator
agreement, below. If the agreement changes, existing moderators will be
required to accept the new terms to maintain their access.
The terms of the agreement
I acknowledge and agree that as a volunteer moderator on Stack Overflow
and/or Stack Exchange sites owned by Stack Exchange, Inc.:

I will abide by the current Code of Conduct (which is a
part of this agreement), and enforce it to the best of my ability.

I will abide by the current Terms of
Service of
Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites (which are part of this
agreement).

I will abide by the Privacy
Policy.

I will abide by all other officially announced moderator and user
policies made available to me.

I will accept additional guidance given by members of the Stack
Exchange, Inc. Community Team and Senior Leadership Team, whether in
response to questions, concerns or discussions regarding existing
network-wide policies.

I acknowledge that I have access to additional personally-identifying
information about Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange users as a
moderator. Some of this information may be subject to GDPR and other
privacy rules. In connection with my access to and/or use of
Moderator-privileged personally identifying information:

I will use such information solely in accordance with the terms of
this moderator agreement and other policies, instructions and
procedures Stack Exchange, Inc. provides to moderators.
I will not disclose or share this information with anyone that is
not a moderator or employee of Stack Exchange, Inc.
I will not store or copy this information for any reason other than
communications with other moderators or employees of Stack Exchange,
Inc.
I will only use such information in connection with performance as a
moderator and for the benefit of Stack Exchange, Inc.


I grant permission to Stack Exchange, Inc. to contact me about
moderator-relevant content during my tenure as a moderator.


I acknowledge and agree that I am an independent volunteer moderator for
one or more sites operated by Stack Exchange, Inc. and I am not an
employee, agent or representative of Stack Exchange, Inc., and I have no
authority to bind Stack Exchange, Inc. in any manner and I am solely
responsible for my statements and actions. I attest that my statements
and posts do not represent the views, opinions or actions of Stack
Exchange, Inc.
Stack Exchange, Inc. reserves the right to suspend or terminate my
privileges as a moderator at any time without warning in the event Stack
Exchange, Inc. determines I have violated any of these terms. Whenever
possible, moderator removal will follow Stack Exchange, Inc.’s
moderator removal
processes.
I will be informed via written communication of the specific reason that
I have been terminated. I have the option to appeal termination through
the moderator reinstatement and appeal
process.
Stack Exchange, Inc. agrees that it will:

Respect your privacy per the terms of the Privacy
Policy for the Public
Network.
Get your explicit written permission before commenting to any media
(including media outlets controlled by Stack Exchange Inc.) or
independent reporters about you or your moderator actions as per our
Press
Policy.
Allow you to resign your position for any reason without penalty or
repercussions. As a volunteer, Stack Exchange, Inc. respects your time
and will release you from duty should you ask.
Operate “Stack Gives Back”, an annual program giving to selected
charities in honor of our moderators.
Post previews for review of all new official policies in the
Moderators Teams instance with the policy tag, marked with links to
their public version once published, and maintain a listing of all
official network-wide policies with links to them in the Help Center.
Announce changes to the moderator agreement no less than sixty days
before the deadline to accept the new agreement with a period of at
least thirty days for discussion and review.
Provide support for your questions, requests and concerns on the
Moderators Teams instance and/or the Teachers’ Lounge, direct email to
CMs, and content on Meta escalated to staff by whatever formal
documented process is in effect at the time.
Respect your right to speak openly to question and challenge policy
without reprisal so long as such speech does not break the Code of
Conduct.

